# Python- Function (generator) which value is list of sequence - beginner

Tags: python, string, list, function, generator

I must create a function(generator) `f(n)`, which will return all of sequence(list) where the difference between within word is greater than 1.
For example,if we use:

```
for i in f(5):
     print(i)
```

The output is:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[1,3]
[2,4]
[3,5]
[1,4]
[2,5]
[1,5]
[1,3,5]
```

How can I do that?

```
def f(n):
  for i in range(1,n+1,2):
    yield i
for i in f(5):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Why have you made all of your code *italic*? Also, do you mean a string, or a list?

Comment: What does "difference between within word is greather than 1" mean? Can you describe your problem a different way?

Comment: Where did the upper limit of 5 in `f` come from?

Comment: I mean list of sequence, I fixed: f(5) - should be. You must look at the example, maybe now is clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can achieve this with recursion:

```
def f(n):
    return f_2(n, 2)
def f_2(n, index):
    if n is index:
        for i in range(1,n+1,1):
            yield [i]
        return
    for start in range(1, n-index+1):
        l=[]
        for j in range(start,n+1,index):
            l.append(j)
            if len(l) > 1:
                yield l
    for value in f_2(n, index+1):
        yield value
for i in f(5):
    print(i)
```

> produces:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 4]
[3, 5]
[1, 4]
[2, 5]
[1, 5]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
```